# Suggest Possible ROM chips and RAM chip that can be interfaced to STM32F407 for TouchGFX

Tags: framebuffer, stm32f4, flash-memory, stm32cubemx, touchgfx

I have STM32F407 Boards like STM32F407 Disco board (without TFT) and some basic Chinese Boards. I have interfaced my TFT LCD with the board using FSMC interface and done basics like text, graphic shapes and images. So the driver is in place I think.

Now I want to introduce Touchgfx to make my GUI lively. But as far as I understand STM32F407 needs external RAM and ROM to store images and  full frame buffer to be used by touchgfx to be more effective. Also FreeRTOS and my application code also needs to be added.

So which are the possible ROM and RAM chip options I can use for this purpose. BGA type RAM or high pin count ICS are not practical my case.

Please suggest.

Thank you

Comment: This question is not suitable for stack overflow; hardware questions have to go on electronics.stackexchange.com, (but while I'm here, here is some small advice: step up to the stm32f429.  The price is about the same and almost everything is compatible, but it supports SDRAM not just SRAM, and has a TFT controller and 2D DMA engine for image processing. Buy a cheap STM32F429I-DISC1 board as a starting point, use the same RAM as is on that board).

Comment: Seconding the stm32f429

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have located some Chinese boards for this purpose. The ROM in that board is small Pin count, but RAM is with lot of Pins. But for the present STM32F407 boards I have a  few,  I think I need to live with partial frame buffer.